# How do I configure a APC Back-UPS XS 1300 with apcupsd?

Tags: 12.04, ups

How do I configure apcupsd to work with a Back-UPS XS 1300?

Answer (score 3):

1) Edit `/etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf` to include a UPSNAME, change `UPSCABLE` and `USPTYPE` to `usb` and comment the device line, for example:

```
UPSNAME KyleUPS
UPSCABLE usb
#UPSTYPE apcsmart
UPSTYPE usb
#DEVICE /dev/ttyS0
```

2) In `/etc/default/apcupsd` change  `ISCONFIGURED` to yes:

`ISCONFIGURED=yes`

3) Start `apcupsd` with:

`sudo service apcupsd start`

4) Test with the `apcaccess` command:

```
kbrandt@alpine:/var/log$ sudo apcaccess
APC      : 001,036,0901
DATE     : 2012-05-05 14:46:50 -0500  
HOSTNAME : alpine
VERSION  : 3.14.10 (13 September 2011) debian
UPSNAME  : KyleUPS
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2012-05-05 14:38:45 -0500  
MODEL    : Back-UPS XS 1300G 
STATUS   : ONLINE 
LINEV    : 115.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :  22.0 Percent Load Capacity
```